# C++: different auto-indentation for function protoypes versus continuation lines

Tags: indentation, autocmd, filetype-python, filetype-c++

I have the following options setup for C++ and Python development in vim:

```
autocmd BufEnter *.cpp setlocal tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 textwidth=80 noexpandtab cindent cinoptions=:0,l1,t0,g0,(0
autocmd BufEnter *.py  setlocal tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 textwidth=79 expandtab   cindent cinoptions=:0,l1,t0,g0,(0
```

In Python, when I am manually creating continuation lines (i.e. to keep code from spilling past a certain column number), auto-indenting and auto-alignment (i.e. visual selection, <kbd>g</kbd>,<kbd>q</kbd>), I encounter very different behavior for Python versus C++ code. For example:

#### Example: Works in C++ and Python Code.

```
val = some_class.some_function(this_is_a_variable_1, this_is_a_variable_2, this_is_a_variable_3, this_is_a_variable_4)
```

Becomes:

```
val = some_class.some_function(this_is_a_variable_1, this_is_a_variable_2,
                               this_is_a_variable_3, this_is_a_variable_4)
```

However, there is different behavior for C++ and Python code with the following example(s):

#### Example: Python Behavior (Desired).

If I insert a newline after the bracket `(` character, the following continuation format occurs:

```
val = some_class.some_function(this_is_a_variable_1, this_is_a_variable_2, this_is_a_variable_3, this_is_a_variable_4)
```

Becomes:

```
val = some_class.some_function(
    this_is_a_variable_1, this_is_a_variable_2, this_is_a_variable_3,
    this_is_a_variable_4)
```

#### Example: C++ Behavior (Not Desired).

If I insert a newline after the bracket `(` character, the following continuation format occurs:

```
val = some_class.some_function(this_is_a_variable_1, this_is_a_variable_2, this_is_a_variable_3, this_is_a_variable_4)
```

Becomes:

```
val = some_class.some_function(
                               this_is_a_variable_1, this_is_a_variable_2,
                               this_is_a_variable_3, this_is_a_variable_4)
```

**This behavior is desirable for function prototypes/declarations, but not for general code.**

## Question

How do I get C++ auto-indentation/auto-formatting to behave the same as Python does (given the above examples) in VIM (i.e. have the continuation line use a single-tab or double-tab, rather than aligning with the opening bracket)?

## Thoughts/Work So Far

Since the above indentation for C++ is only used for function declarations/prototypes, maybe I could write a macro to apply that specific indentation to a visual selection, and disable that formatting option in general.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. [From the documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html#cinoptions-values): **`(0,W8`**.

[I found the following somewhat related answer on another SE site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/699313/1022889), to explain why I use a double-indent (i.e. `(0,W8` instead of `(0,W4`) for continuation lines (i.e. Google and Oracle style guides encourage it).

```
WN    When in unclosed parentheses and N is non-zero and either
      using "(0" or "u0", respectively and the unclosed parentheses is
      the last non-white character in its line and it is not the
      closing parentheses, indent the following line N characters
      relative to the outer context (i.e. start of the line or the
      next unclosed parentheses).  (default: 0).

        cino=(0                    cino=(0,W4
          a_long_line(              a_long_line(
                      argument,         argument,
                      argument);        argument);
          a_short_line(argument,    a_short_line(argument,
                       argument);                argument);
```